# class function partial specialization with templated argument

Tags: c++, templates, containers, specialization

I would like to have a Queue template class which can specify the internal container structure via the template argument and specialize the Top function (as different container use different function name for accessing the front item), like the following code:

```
template<class I, class C = std::queue<I>>
class Queue
{
    C items;
public:
    I* Top()
    {
        std::cout << "this is a queue" << std::endl;
        return &items.front();
    }
};

template<class I>
void I* Queue<I, std::priority_queue<I>>::Top()
{
    std::cout << "this is a priority_queue" << std::endl;
    return &items.top();
}
```

However, this piece of codes cause a lot compilation errors. Does anyone could give me a hint that am I going into a wrong direction of designing the template class? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is a `void I*` anyway?, and regardless, `items` is of type C, and no magic in a single member function is going to change that.

Comment: Oops... sorry... it is a typo. The return type of the Top() function should be I* instead of void I*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to partially specialise a (member) function template. Function templates cannot be partially specialised in C++. You'd have to partially specialise the entire class, or find other ways of doing what you want. For example, you could use a trait in `Top()`:

```
I* Top()
{
    return MyQueueTraits<I, C>::GetTop(items);
}

template <class I, class C>
struct MyQueueTraits
{
  static I* GetTop(C &c) { return &c.front(); }
};

template <class I>
struct MyQueueTraits<I, std::priority_queue<I>>
{
  static I* GetTop(std::pirority_queue<I> &c) { return &c.top(); }
};
```

Comment: Yes! It works for my implementation. Thanks a lot! :)